# PyTorch says NO cuda GPU found on Colab however torch.cuda.is_available() is True

Tags: pytorch, google-colaboratory

Is there any way around to get GPU on colab

```
import torch
print(torch.version)
print(torch.cuda.is_available())
```

Error:

```
RuntimeError: No CUDA GPUs are available
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to activate GPU computing in Google colab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61210095/how-to-activate-gpu-computing-in-google-colab)

Comment: I already activated GPU by using shell script thats why torch.cuda.is_available() is returning true.

Comment: Ok, when is this error raised?